# get oozie-client dependency with Gradle build

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, oozie

I'm trying to build my project using IntelliJ and gradle. I have a dependency on oozie-client jar.

I defined the dependency in gradle as follows:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.yahoo.oozie:oozie-core:3.0.0'
}
```

when I run buildDependency I get the following error:
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.

> Could not resolve com.yahoo.oozie:oozie-core:3.0.0.
>     Required by:
>         :TestRunnerFramework:1.0
>   Could not resolve com.yahoo.oozie:oozie-core:3.0.0.
>   Could not parse POM http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/yahoo/oozie/oozie-core/3.0.0/oozie-core-3.0.0.pom
>   Could not find any version that matches com.yahoo.oozie:oozie-main:3.0.0.

please advice,

Answer (score 0):

This is either an incorrect POM (or incorrect parent POM), or a POM that Gradle fails to interpret correctly (there are a few known limitations around this). Often, the only solution is to edit the POM, for example in your binary artifact repository. If you think the problem is on Gradle's side, you can file an issue over at http://forums.gradle.org.